# parse the JSON object returned as response

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id1').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:" ggs.erm.servlet.setup5.Page",
            success:function(response){
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(obj);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am facing problem with parsing JSON object i receive from server.

```
Connection con = null;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
try{
    con =ConnectionPool.getConnection();
    String sql = "select country from country_name";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        jarray.put(rs.getString(1));    
    }
    json.put("country", jarray);
}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
finally{
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    try {
        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is code for generating json.
Problem is How to parse the JSON object I get on Client Side.

Comment: What does your json string look like? what error are you getting?

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.parse` as this should be done automatically if the content-type is application/json.

Comment: when i Run servlet code, I get JSON :{"country":"[\"AFGHANISTAN\",\"ALBANIA\",\"ALGERIA\",\"AMERICAN SAMOA\"]"}. on Client side : object[] {somethibg like it} pop ups in alert Box,Instead it I want What is inside JSON .

Comment: What do you get if you call `alert(response)`? I would expect your returned object to have a property called `country` which is an array of string: `obj.country[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `alert()` to debug. It just gives you the `toString()` value, which is `[object Object]`.

Instead, log the object  to the console.

```
console.log(response);

// or

var obj = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(obj);
```

Open the developer tools in your browser to view the content of the object.

Comment: I am working on autocompleting using ajax : so code for it  is :->$("#id").autocomplete({source:var_name}); Here var_name should be a JSON string . How to put the JSON string which i get in response in var_name. Will Var var_name = response work????